# Rename route php or index.php in url Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I currently working on two applications in one codeigniter installation.
The structured of the applications is:

```
somewebsite.com (main directory)
- webdesktop (directory)
- webmobile (directory)
- index.php (for webdesktop)
- mobile.php (for webmobile)
- .htaccess
```

I managed to remove the index.php to access the webdesktop app (`http://somewebsite.com/index.php/controller` to `http://somewebsite.com/controller`) using these config:

config.php (webdesktop):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://somewebsite.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The problem that I face right know is the url to access webmobile. I currently access it using this url : `http://somewebsite.com/mobile.php/controller`.

How to change `mobile.php` to just `mobile`? so the url to access webmobile can become `http://somewebsite.com/mobile/controller`.

Comment: codeigniter url follows like www.domainname.com/foldername/controllername/method

Answer (score 1):

Just add this rule at your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^mobile$ mobile.php
```

It will read `mobile` as `mobile.php`. So, if you need other changes to your URL, you can learn about htaccess rules.

Hopefully can help you.